# retrieve json array from $.post()

Tags: php, jquery, json

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#asd").click(function(){
    $.post("/sister/rest/rest/login",
    {
      email:"t@s.com",
      pwd:11
    },
    function(data){
      $('#id3').append(data.user_fullname);
    });
  });
});

</script>
```

when i cliked the #asd, #id3 shows "ch", the json array from   `/sister/rest/rest/login` `[{"user_id":"1","user_fullname":"ch","user_email":"t@s.com"}]`

when i tried the `$('#id3').append(data[0].user_fullname);` it showed nothing :(, why?

im newbie in getting json data, so please help me! Thank you all

Comment: Have you check your data is empty anot?

Comment: @edisonthk how to check?

Comment: add console.log(data) to your callback function.

Comment: check whether the return content is sending the json data with the correct json headers, otherwise it will just be a string and not an object thus data.user_fullname will not work

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the JSON object before trying to pull out the elements. You do this by using `JSON.parse()`

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#asd").click(function(){
    $.post("/sister/rest/rest/login",
    {
      email:"t@s.com",
      pwd:11
    },
    function(data){
      data = JSON.parse(data);
      $('#id3').append(data.user_fullname);
    });
  });
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[{"user_id":"1","user_fullname":"ch","user_email":"t@s.com"}
```

Looks like you are missing a closing tag.

```
[{"user_id":"1","user_fullname":"ch","user_email":"t@s.com"}]
```

I use [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) to quickly validate JSON and determine where is the issue.